# How to create a database in Oracle8 Lite with Developer 2000?

Tags: oracle

I am new in Oracle. I install Oracle 8 Lite with Developer 2000. Now I want to create a database for me. For that I open Oracle8 Navigator and Create a database which user is system. But in Oracle SQL*Plus I can not communicate with the database. Or even after creating a table using Oracle8 Navigator I can't alter the table.

Please tell me how can I alter my table?

Comment: Tareq, this sonds like a setup/configuration problem to me. Since Oracle IS a server product I suggest this question be moved to ServerFault.com.

Comment: @Iexu - Actually Oracle Lite is a database for mobile applications, so in this particular case it is *not* a server product.

Comment: Why are you using such old technologies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are dealing with.
There is an Oracle Lite database for PDAs, mobile devices etc. But that went from version 5 to 9.

There was a standard Oracle 8 database (8 and 8i) which is markedly different, especially when it comes to Developer/2000.

Finally, Oracle 8 and Developer/2000 are pretty long in the tooth. I wouldn't recommend trying to learn off them unless it is for a specific job that uses those technologies. [Similar with Oracle Lite].

I'd recommend looking for Oracle XE (Express Edition) and the Apex development environment as a good way to start to learn Oracle.